# iPhone possible hacking

Tags: iphone, messages

My young daughter tried to contact her friend via iMessage. Her friend's account is set up via her father's email address. My daughter later received *unsavoury* texts back. She deleted these straight away as there were swear words and she felt guilty about them.

One message remained on the iPod. It came from the father's email address, he claims that there must be a crossed line or his iPhone has been hacked.

**Is either of this possible?**

Comment: Both of these scenarios are possible but not likely.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Facetime" texting. FaceTime is used for video messaging, exclusively. I think you mean iMessage (the text bubbles are blue). There have been reports in the past where stolen devices were still able to receive messages despite the original owner signing out of the service or even canceling the SIM, but those have likely been dealt with by Apple. It's probably more likely that one of your daughter's friends got a hold of the phone and were playing with her.

Comment: Yes, I beleive it is imessage. But there is no way it would have been one of my daughters friends as the obscene words use are not in their vocabulary, they are to young.

Comment: At this point, it hasn't been figured out how to "hack" an iPhone in the same way you might a PC (in other words, "remotely control a device maliciously"). So his iPhone probably hasn't been "hacked". However, It is possible to "hack" an email account, and, as a result, someone could theoretically login with that email account on their iOS device, and use that maliciously. This process seems unlikely, though. Is it possible the email was misspelled somehow? Are there other variables that might be impacting this situation?

Comment: The iPhone might have been set up with a different DNS sever, perhaps via a malicious configuration profile or otherwise. This DNS server could forward information to another system, and that system could possibly send information back. Whilst unlikely, it's still a possibility.

Comment: The probability of the device being hacked is near 0. The probability of the Apple ID being compromised is remote too as iOS informs you when a new device is registered to use the service. So it makes it extremely difficult to monitor chats without the original party knowing. Someone local sending those messages is the likeliest scenario in terms of probability.

Answer (score 1):

Iphone, was not hacked. wasn't crossed. Husband was arrested and admitted to charges.

Thanks for help, it confirmed that the device was probably not compromised.

Answer (score 0):

If the father has plugged his Apple ID into any other iOS devices during their initial setup, those devices by default are provisioned to use that Apple ID for iMessage. With that in mind, it is quite possible that a sibling or even other friend or family member of the father has his account installed.

If the father insists he is not sending the messages, he needs to reset his Apple ID password immediately. This will ensure that whatever unsavory character he lent his Apple ID to is no longer sending your daughter inappropriate messages, and is frankly the only responsible thing for him to do.

Comment: At the time the messages were received and the age of the kids,I think the probability is that the device was hacked. I just thought this was near on impossible.

Comment: Yes, unless an iPhone is jailbroken it is not possible to hack an iPhone or spoof an iMessage.